# Add suffix to line containing varying numbers using Notepad++

Tags: regex

I have an xml file which I need to edit - and I was wondering how about I would go finding each instance of a varying number - eg/ `<g:id>33</g:id>` and replacing it by adding a suffix to each eg/ `<g:id>33_abc</g:id>` This suffix would remain the same.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find what:

```
<g:id>(\d+)</g:id>
```

Replace with:

```
<g:id>\1_abc</g:id>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have list of tables : e.g

```
types
status
users
messages
```

If I want to delete the data in these table and reset auto_increment I ll do sth:

```
Find What: ^(.+)$
Replace with :delete from \1 ; \nalter table \1  auto_increment=0;
```

you will get:

```
delete from types ; 
alter table types  auto_increment=0;
delete from status ; 
alter table status  auto_increment=0;
delete from users ; 
alter table users  auto_increment=0;
delete from messages ; 
alter table messages  auto_increment=0;
```

Although its unrelated but shows a possible  application